# jQuery animate to top function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add jQuery smooth scrolling, clicking the button gets me to the top of the page but the animation is not working.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
            $('.fa-chevron-up').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.fa-chevron-up').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.fa-chevron-up').click(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

This is the button that appears when scrolling -

```
<a href="#" class="scrolltotop"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

Tried jQuery(document) still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: If it helps any, here's a cleaner version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/2048a6c5/

Comment: Stop wasting your fingers writing `jQuery` all over the place and use the alias `$` - thanks to `jQuery(function($) {` instead of your `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Also stop misusing `return false;` Propagation is always a good thing. Instead use the function first argument `event` and do `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrolltotop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrolltotop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrolltotop').click(function(e) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 800);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
a.scrolltotop {
  bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.content {
  height: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="#" class="scrolltotop"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>^ Up</a>
```

The animation is not working because it is not being called. The reason the page scrolls back to the top is because you are effectively navigating to an undefined anchor (`href="#"`).

Change this:

```
jQuery('.fa-chevron-up').click(function(){
```

To this:

```
jQuery('.scrolltotop').click(function() {
```

Since font-awesome icons generally work by assigning a character as a pseudo-element of the element the classes are applied to, it is possible that if you click directly on the icon, it might work as expected. In any case, you should apply the click handler to the `a` tag element via the `.scrolltotop` selector.

Note: I've also updated the selectors for the fade behavior.

Comment: Being the issue or not it's an amazing suggestion. CSS/styling-related classes should never be misused for JS purpose. `.js-scrollToTop` is even better because anyone by reading the HTML markup will know there's JS involved on that element.

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {` is a better alternative to `$(document).ready(function(){` because it encompasses the `$` alias into it's own scope.

Comment: thank you, adding  ".scrolltotop" instead of ".fa-chevron-up" worked. Marked as accepted answer